# How can I configure Excel cells to show "#h #min" conveniently?

Tags: excel

I want to save the duration of some courses in my excel file.
For this I want to have the cell show i. e. "2h 23min".
And I want it to be convenient like typing in a date.
This means that I want the cell to show `2h 23min` when I type in `2 23` and `0h 30min` when I type `0 30` and so on.
Similar to the behavior when the cell is formatted to show a date.

How can I achieve such behavior?

Comment: That will take vba in a worksheet change event.

Comment: @ScottCraner What's that?

Comment: If you do not mind typing `2:23` instead then you simply would format the cells `[h]\h m\m\i\n`

Comment: `2 23` is not a natural recognized time format and as such you will need to parse the string to create a time.  If you want to do this in place, then it will take code.  VBA is the code that Excel uses to create custom procedures.  It is part of Excel.  The Worksheet_change is an event that gets fired whenever the value changes on the worksheet.  It is used to run the vba code whenever something changes.  This will not be able to be done in place with out custom code running in the back ground.

Comment: @ScottCraner That sounds interesting. Can you explain it further please (might as well do it as an answer).

Comment: no, asking for code is out of scope here.

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't see how it is out of scope if it answers the question and is excel related.

Comment: Because to truly answer the question I would need to write the code and also explain how to use it and how to access the VBE.  I would basically need to teach you a course on coding in VBA.  That is too broad and off topic.  This site is to help those with a specific problem with their existing code.  The line gets blurred when the fix is easy one line or formula, but when it comes to vba most of the time we ask that the OP show some code attempt.  You can wait, some point seeker may stumble through and do it even though they shouldn't.  I am not one of those.